# How to show hide loading bar automatically in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I would like to show a loading bar when a request is made to backend, I have declared interceptor for request and response as follow:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    console.log("before request");
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    console.log("before request error");
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    console.log("after request completed success");
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    console.log("after request completed error");
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

The idea is that I would like to have a variable or some kind of state that I can show loading bar depending while request is made and not finished, and hide it when receiving the response!

I have a loading bar component separate as below:

```
export default class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Progress.Circle size={60} indeterminate={true}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to create a const value on a separate file smth like **isLoading: false** and then change it from the intereceptors but for some reason its not working the way I want, so that the loading bar shows and hides depending on the value of the isLoading variable!

Comment: you can use redux.

Comment: @Vivek_Neel are there other alternatives for achieving this without using redux? heard redux is not nececarly for smaller projects like the one I am working!

Comment: Then have `isLoading` as state property in your component. Change isLoading accordingly

Comment: u mean inside ProgressBar component? if so, how can I update its value state for isLoading from within axios.interceptors.response or request? can we somehow change other components states from another place?

Comment: Where is your axios stuffs reside? And in which component are you trying to render progress?

Comment: I have Main Component, ProgressBar Component and I have a file separate into some folder called config where it is axios configs and interceptors are there declared, I can actually see the logs in console and I can say that those intereceptors are called and working fine, the idea is how to now show progressbar according to the intereceptors.

I am trying to show progressBar inside Main COmponent!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169231/discussion-between-vivek-neel-and-mizlul).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need axios interceptor for you to display a loader when data is being processed. One suggestion I can give you is to make sure whenever you trigger the action creator, set your component localState to a variable to a boolean true and set it to false when the value is received, that way you can manipulate the display of the spinner depending on the actual value.

An example is given below:

```
class LoaderExample extends Component {

state = { 

   isLoading: true

 }

  componentDidMount(){

   this.setState({ isLoading: true })

   this.props.makeApiCall()
    .then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }))
}

  render(){
     return(
      {
      this.state.isLoading && <SpinnerComponent/>

      }
    )
}

}
```

***Just an example, you can modify it to suit your solution.***

Comment: how are you changing the state of isLoading when a call to backend is made?

Comment: also I dont make API calls from within Loader

Comment: that means everytime I make an api call I have to maintain the isLoading , which is not a good way, that's why I am using intereceptors to automatically detect request calls and responses so I can only mantain the state of isLoading from there!

Comment: I already explained it, each time u make api call you have to mantain isLoading manually from every component, while using intereceptors u can maintain isLoading state from one place only!

Comment: Okay, cool then dispatch an action whenever a request is in process.